# Reading from a dictionary in Swift - Not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary, double

I am building a game in Xcode and I'm storing the details for the level in text files e.g. Level1.txt, Level2.txt etc.

I read in the data from a text file and store it in a Dictionary.
When I try to assign the values from the dictionary to the global variables, it doesn't work.

**Text File Contents (Level1.txt)**

```
 LevelNum:1 
 weaponPickupRate:10.0
 weaponPickupAmount:50.0
 monsterMinSpeed:10.0
 monsterMaxSpeed:15.0
 monsterRate:1.0
 totalMonsters:10.0
 goldPerMonster:10
```

**Global Variables**

```
var settings = [String: Any]()
var monsterMaxSpeed = 0.0
```

**Function For Obtaining Level Details**

```
func GenerateLevel(levelNumber: Int) {

    fileName = "level\(levelNumber).txt"
    levelPath = "\(NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!)/\(fileName)"

    var err: NSError? = NSError()
    let s = String(contentsOfFile: levelPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &err)

    if let content = s {
        var array = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

        for a in array {
            var v = a.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
            settings[v[0]] = v[1]
        }

    }

    println(settings) // A

    var e = settings["monsterMaxSpeed"]
    println(e) // B

    monsterMaxSpeed = settings["monsterMaxSpeed"] // C

 }
```

**Println(setting) (A) - prints:**

[monsterRate: 1.0, monsterMinSpeed: 10.0, weaponPickupRate: 10.0, weaponPickupAmount: 50.0, goldPerMonster: 10, totalMonsters: 10.0, LevelNum: 1, monsterMaxSpeed: 15.0]

**Println(e) (B) prints:**

Optional("15.0")

**This Line Does not work**

it shows up an error and doesn't allow me to build my project. The Error given is:

'(String, Any)' is not convertible to 'Double'

```
monsterMaxSpeed = settings["monsterMaxSpeed"]
```

Please can someone help and advise me what I need to do?

Thanks,

Ryann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here.

First, fetching from a `[String:Any]` dictionary by key does not return an `Any`.  It returns an `Any?` i.e. an optional that may or may not contain an `Any`.  This is because that key may not be present in the dictionary.

You need to test if the value is non-nil and unwrap the value if it is:

```
if let speed = settings["monsterMaxSpeed"] {
    monsterMaxSpeed = speed
}
else {
    // handle there being no speed setting in your file
    // by reporting an error or similar
}
```

Or, if you’re happy with just using a default, you can use the nil coalescing operator:

```
// if the key is present, us the unwrapped value, if not use 0.0
monsterMaxSpeed = settings["monsterMaxSpeed"] ?? 0.0
```

Second, you’ve declared `monsterMaxSpeed` as a `Double` not an `Any`.  So once you resolve your optional unwrapping problem you’ll get a second problem.  You need to convert the `Any` to a `Double` using `as?`.  The `?` in `as?` is important – if the value is not a double (suppose there was a rogue character in the entry in your file), you will get a `nil` back.  Again, you would need to test for this and handle the error.

Happily, you can do this all in one go:

```
monsterMaxSpeed = (settings["monsterMaxSpeed"] as? Double) ?? 0.0
```

(it’s probably the confluence of the two of these issues that’s causing you to get a particularly enigmatic error – the error relates to the *other* version of `Dictionary.subscript` which takes an index, not a key, and returns a key/value pair, which isn’t optional, because indices should only address entries that are definitely in the dictionary)

Comment: This is such great help. Thank you so much. One last question, if it wasn't a double and it was a String.. what would I need to change? Double to String and 0.0 to what? Cheers again, Ryann

Comment: So whatever default is appropriate for your use case, but a string rather than a number.  Maybe an empty string (“”), maybe “Error”. Or you don’t have to default it, you could raise an error with if/else.

Comment: I have been continuing to build the game however when I use as you shown above 'monsterMaxSpeed = settings["monsterMaxSpeed"] ?? 0.0' or whenever i use it for anything else within the dictionary, everything i returned as 0.0. Why is this?